# removing paddling between two span elements

Tags: html, css

I try to remove padding between two span elements which is not working, i did padding and margin set to 0px but didn't work

```
span {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

somehow div container occupies some default padding which creates problem, someone can help to solve this issue

http://jsfiddle.net/f30boLhu/

here i want to remove black marked space between two texts

[image]

Comment: Fiddle shows something else

Comment: sorry, i just update link

Comment: update the line-height

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add some style with existing code for your second `span` whose having `promise` class, See below CSS code -

Or try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsgo4p75/)

CSS Code-

```
.promise {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: My Pleasure :) @Urock

Answer (score 1):

you can play with line-height or add a `height` to `.bonus`

```
  .bonus {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to put span tags together like:
`<span>one</span><span>two</span>`
Without any separate between them